# Binding from UI to view model property requires focus to be removed from the TextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am using MVVM. I have a DataGrid which lists some airports. Now I have a textbox let the user to input some keywords to search for a particular airport so that the airport list will only display matched airports.

```
private string airport;
public string Airport
{
    get { return airport; }

    //the following will not be executed unless the cursor is removed from the textbox
    set
    {
        airport = value;
        //OnPropertyChanged("Airport");
    }
}
```

view:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox_Airport" Text="{Binding Airport}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Command_Airport}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

The problem is that the value of "Airport" will not be transmitted from UI to Property unless the focus is removed from the textbox, hence it leads to a null value exception in the command. I think to use a button for search instead of using "TextChanged" event could solve this but not user-friendly enough. How can I keep the "TextChanged" way and solve this using MVVM? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default mode of updating source for TextBox.Text property is `LostFocus`. Change it to `PropertyChanged`.

`Text="{Binding Airport, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

And if you are working with .net 4.5 or newer, I suggest to use binding `Delay` as well. With Delay `Airport` property will be updated after user stopped typing, not on every key press. Search in this case can be triggered from `Airport` setter, which should allow user to type full search keyword, before actually searching it

`Text="{Binding Airport, Delay=400, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`